# How to convert usd to website's own currency and save after finishing online payment using PayPal

Tags: paypal

I have an online store. I have currency called **fcoin** on my website.

I am using **PayPal** as payment system.

I have column called **fcoinvalue** inside my **mysql databese.**

My exchange rate is **1USD = 1fcoin**

**Question:**

1. is it possible after finishing transaction by user to detect transaction amount and save value inside **fcoinvalue** column using **php or/and javascript?**

**Scenario for simplicity:**

Let's say user needs to enable websites premium feature to place ads on homepage. if user funds USD 10 through PayPal he/she must see 10 fcoin inside **website's wallet.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. The first step is to get the transaction amount, which will depend on how you are integrated with PayPal. A [server integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls) is preferred for this scenario. You'll need two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one  for 'Capture Order'. These routes should return JSON data, so they can be paired with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

When a capture is successful, you should check for this before returning the JSON response, and if so update your database to record the order received.  (In your case this apparently means updating an **fcoin** wallet balance for the user.)